# Javascript while loop changing scroll position of div crashes site

Tags: javascript, html, crash, scroll, while-loop

I have a div displaying some horizontally scrollable images with `white-space:nowrap; overflow-x:scroll` and i'm trying to make the function below work:

```
var mouseIsInDiv = false;
function autoScroll() {
var i = 1;
while (mouseIsInDiv = false) {
    setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("theDiv").scrollLeft = i;
    i++;
    },50);
}
}
```

It is supposed to loop through (while the mouse is not within this scrollable div) incrementing the scroll position by 1px every 50 miliseconds. In other words it's supposed to scroll through the images automatically when this function is called. I'm not getting any syntactic errors but whenever i press a button that calls this function on a webpage, the browser crashes completely - I'm using the latest versions of Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Any ideas would be really helpful, I've been tearing my hair out over this!

Comment: It's probably `while (!mouseIsInDiv) {...` and you should probably stop that loop somewhere, otherwise it will go for ever, and all the timeouts will occur pretty much after 50ms, as they are async, and the next iteration won't wait for those to finish ?

Comment: Either that or `mouseIsInDiv == false`. Classic language semantic error.

Comment: @adeneo I thought it probably is, but I don't see what's wrong? The loop will be stopped by another function that changes mouseIsInDiv to true and also (eventually once this works) by the scroll reaching the end. :)

Comment: There is no other function, the loop is not async, once it's running, you can't call another function, unless you do it in the loop, and not in the timeout either. The timeouts will all execute in 50 milliseconds, as the loop runs thru and finishes within milliseconds, as it does'nt wait for the timeouts to finish.

Comment: @AustinMullins Can't believe I missed that! Thanks, I'll try it out with that corrected...

Comment: @adeneo Ah... Ok makes sense so setInterval is the way to go?

Comment: Not inside the loop, but if you remove the while condition and think you can make it work with a setInterval, sure, no problem!

Comment: @adeneo Fantastic just a bit of sillyness on my part then! Thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop creates many timeouts that happens in the same time (after 50 milisecs) you need to set the timeout recursivly, inside the set timeout function, and ask if mouseISInDiv inside the set timeout function as well.

The current code state, the loop will run many many times in a small amount of time, and page will crush(it's liek infinite) and after 50 millisecs there will be many set timeouts that ran.

Answer (score 0):

I had a fun time working on this one, so I'll post my response despite the correct answer already having been accepted.

Basically, you need to restructure everything so that the whole scheme is asynchronous. That means event listeners respond to mouse movement, and there are no while loops.

Thus, I present [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/yRyPb/6/). Here is the javascript:

```
var mouseIsInDiv = false;
var theDiv = document.getElementById("theDiv");
theDiv.onmouseover = function() { mouseIsInDiv = true; };
theDiv.onmouseout = function() {
    mouseIsInDiv = false;
    scrollLeft1();
};

function scrollLeft1() {
  if (mouseIsInDiv == false && theDiv.scrollLeft < theDiv.clientWidth) {
    theDiv.scrollLeft += 1;
    setTimeout(scrollLeft1, 50);
  }
}

scrollLeft1();
```

As you can see, the function calls itself recursively and asynchronously, and the whole thing can be restarted after manually resetting the scroll. You could also add an event listener for the scroll completion.

Comment: Nice one, thanks! I've got it working using setInterval() now too.